# How to totally reset ROS

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am experimenting with many different tutorials and from time to time I find that things start hanging up or getting stuck.  So I kill all my terminal windows and jobs expecting to come back to a clean initial condition. Everything including ROSCORE. Everything that I am aware of of having started. But that doesn't seem to help, things still act a little strange. And in fact at that point (with all the terminal windows killed) if I do a ps -ax I see a number of processes still mentioning ../kinetic/...

However I have found that rebooting my computer altogether and then doing the tutorial again often does the trick. Ok, I know, computers can be like that.

Is there a way short of rebooting to basically kill all ROS related stuff?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280993/how-to-totally-reset-ros/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd recommend getting to know about process control on linux more generally. http://www.hostingadvice.com/blog/linux-process-management-commands-know/

In particular I'd recommend being more careful about how you tear down things. If you're using roslaunch it will work hard to clean up everything if you let it. However if you kill roslaunch hard, it will not have a chance to clean up processes that it started which can leave a lot running on your system.

If you get into that state there are a lot of linux commands that can be used to clean up remant processes. At that point it's not really anything ROS specific but linux specific. It sounds like you already have the ability to find those processes. You will then want to `kill` them using their `PID`. The above link was the first I found on google. There are lots of other tutorials that may be useful to you.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-01-31**:
Thanks, that's helpful. What's the "right" way to kill a roslaunch or rosrun app?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-01-31**:
Press `Ctrl-C` and then wait for it to tear everything down.